# How do I include stylesheets with symfony properly?

Tags: css, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a simple Template (layout.php) and I use Propel as ORM.

When i include sylesheets (into  of layout.php) with the function: `include_stylesheets()` I became 2 css:

> /sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css
>
> /sfPropelORMPlugin/css/default.css

why?

when I look into my view.yml actually I just have this:

```
default:
  http_metas:
    content-type: text/html
  stylesheets:
  has_layout:     true
  layout:         layout
```

I configure no stylesheets but I see Propel css in my Head Tag!

my **generator.yml** :

```
generator:
 class: sfPropelGenerator
 param:

 ##CONFIG##

config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:    ~
  filter:  ~
  form:    ~
  edit:    ~
  new:     ~
```

Is this a bug? or just a misconfiguration?

Comment: Hum, this can't be your generator.yml since it the template and not the one generated in your app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mainly because there are automatically loaded when you use a the admin template ([see this file](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/blob/master/data/generator/sfPropelModule/admin/template/templates/_assets.php)):

```php
<?php if (isset($this->params['css']) && ($this->params['css'] !== false)): ?>
  [?php use_stylesheet('<?php echo $this->params['css'] ?>', 'first') ?]
<?php elseif(!isset($this->params['css'])): ?>
  [?php use_stylesheet('<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_admin_module_web_dir').'/css/global.css' ?>', 'first') ?]
  [?php use_stylesheet('<?php echo sfConfig::get('sf_admin_module_web_dir').'/css/default.css' ?>', 'first') ?]
<?php endif; ?>
```

This means you can define your own css in the `generator.yml` (and it won't load the default ones), like :

```yml
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    css:          /css/my_css.css
```

Or removed them:

```yml
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    css:          false
```

**edit:**

And finally you can remove them from the `view.yml`:

```yml
default:
  http_metas:
    content-type: text/html
  stylesheets:
    - -/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css
    - -/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/default.css
  has_layout:     true
  layout:         layout
```

Comment: dont work! i still have into "cache/../_assets.php" the "use_stylesheet('/sfPropelORMPlugin/css/global.css')"!

Comment: jep! twice! for the both cases! but always see the PropelORM css!

Comment: Could you post your generator.yml in your question ?

Comment: i edited my post! thx! i should mentionned that the "/sfPropelORMPlugin/..." Path also return a 404 error...

Comment: The 404 is because you don't have published your assets: `./symfony plugin:publish-assets`