# How to use a custom CSS file in an admin generator (for sfGuardUser)?

Tags: css, symfony1, admin-generator

I want to add my own css to sfGuardUser model

I have this kind of configuration in `generator.yml`

```
generator:
class:              sfPropelAdminGenerator
param:
  model_class:      sfGuardUser
  theme:            default
  css:              foomain
```

The css-line is what I added for testing, because I would want to get rid of `/sf/sf_admin/css/main.css` that is automatically added to those views.

What next? What should I type to generate new thingies for this? I mean, how do I run generator to generate files in cache-folder? I didn't find any tutorials from web when it comes to updating `generator.yml` settings and creating admin views again.

Comment: They say symfony cache:clear should do it, but new css didn't come up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include stylesheets with symfony properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115222/how-do-i-include-stylesheets-with-symfony-properly). Also check the path of your css. It should be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view.yml in the config directory, and it works the same as your normal modules for the admin generated modules.

See: http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/13-View